# Why is my PDF download corrupted?

Tags: php, html, pdf

I have a script that generates a pdf using fpdf, this file is saved correctly on the server on my computer. In that same php file I run the following code to download the file. When i download the pdf and I check it in notepad, everything in the pdf is the same, except for the fact that it contains a lot of my previous files html at the beginning of it. The file saved to my server doesn't have any of that.

What could cause something like this to happen? I have no idea where to look for the source of this error, can anyone point me in the direction to finding the problem?

```
<?php
$filename=($name.$ran.'.pdf');
$pdf->Output($name.$ran.'.pdf');

header ("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Content-Type: application/octetstream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-length: ".filesize($filename));
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\"");
readfile($name.$ran.'.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: I get the following error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.pdf'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\download.php on line 33

Comment: The output buffer can cause that. Your question most likely does not contain the full example to reproduce this, there is HTML before what you've posted. It goes into the output buffer and then is appended to the response body, that is before the output of `readfile`. See: http://php.net/book.outcontrol

Comment: Do you think clearing the buffer would solve that problem?

Comment: Hey Guys, I managed to figure things out, thanks to hakre! Essentially I just needed to clear out the output buffer using ob_clean () before using readfile() and the code worked!

Comment: You can [post this as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure things out, thanks to hakre! Essentially I just needed to clear out the output buffer using ob_clean () before using readfile() and the code worked!